# SSRS 2016 - 'extension Name' is not valid

Tags: email, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am trying to set up a new subscription in SSRS 2016 and the `Delivery options (E-Mail)` aren't loading.  Here is the error message:

> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
>   The value of parameter 'extension Name' is not valid. (rsInvalidParameter)

[image: error message]

I have the SMTP server setup in the Configuration Manager and have sent test emails with it.  Is there another configuration I might have missed?

Comment: Does your report have a parameter named extensionName?

Comment: No, there are no parameters, it's a very simple report.  I think this error is in relation to something in the generated rsreportserver.config

Comment: Then it must be a misconfiguration when selecting your rendering extensions. Take a look in your RSReportServer.config file for the supported rendering extensions and make sure what you are applying is valid. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/extensions/rendering-extension/rendering-extensions-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up trying to add it using powershell and finally got a useful error message telling me my version of SSRS didn't support adding schedules.

> Exception calling "ListSubscriptions" with "1" argument(s): "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The feature: "Subscriptions to reports" is not supported in 
>   this edition of Reporting Services.

I am using Web, but apparently I need the Standard version to proceed
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reporting-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2016